# Function to check if a range is contained in another

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to create a function that checks if a cell (Range1) is contained within Range2. The function would be:

```
Function IsWithin(Range1 as Range, Range2 as Range) as Boolean
```

This is meant to go in a `Before_DoubleClick` event to check that the cell clicked belongs to a range.

Examples of expected input/output (*using addresses directly only to make it easier to imagine*):

```
IsWithin("A2", "A1:B3") = True
IsWithin("B1","B1:B2") = True
IsWithin("A3", "A4:C10") = False
IsWithin("A3", "A3") = True
```

Off the top of my head I can think of a simple way to do this:

```
Function IsWithin(Range1 as Range, Range2 as Range) as Boolean
    Dim cell2 as range

    For each cell2 in Range2
          If cell2.address = Range1.Address then 
               IsWithin = True
               Exit Function 
          End if 
    Next

End function
```

Now for the harder part, and the question. If I am selecting a Merged cell that protrudes inside Range2, I'd like it to count as being part of the range (even if some of the merged cell sticks out). What would I need to write to get that done?

Example considering `A1:B3` is a merged cell (Still sending addresses instead of range objects as a way to represent it easier):

```
IsWithin("A1:B3", "A2:D7") = True
```

Comment: Will you always be testing a single cell to check whether it is within a larger range? [including the case where a single cell is part of a larger merged area, meaning the whole merged area is checked]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason why you're not using `Intersect()`?

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Intersect(Range("A2"), Range("A1:B3"))

If r Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Not in range"
ElseIf r.Address = Range("A2").Address Then
    Debug.Print "Completely within range"
Else
    Debug.Print "Partially within range"
End If
```

---

**Edit**:

As @Bacon mentioned in the comments, this doesn't work with merged cells. But you can use the `MergeArea` property to test for that. Assuming `A1:B1` is a merged range, this should work:

```
Set r = Intersect(Range("A1").MergeArea, Range("B1:B3"))

If r Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Not in range"
Else
    Debug.Print "Ranges intersect"
End If
```

`MergeArea` returns the merged range, if it's part of a merged area. If not, it just returns the single cell. So you should be safe *always* using `MergeArea` for the source when you test the intersection, as shown above in the edit.

Comment: Oh nice! Great simple way!

Comment: This does not appear to work with the merged cell test - if A1:B2 are merged, and you test whether A1 intersects with B2:C3, it shows "Not in range". But, the merged cell which starts in A1 goes until B2, meaning the merged cell is partially within the range. To solve this problem I think you need to do a loop which goes through all merged cells found in the test area to see what happens.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon - You're right. I added an edit showing how you can test for merged cells using the `MergeArea` property.

Comment: @DavidG To get this to work with merged cells, you simply check to see if your test cell is merged, and if it is, redefine it as the range of the merged area. Like so [this will only work if you are testing a single cell - to expand for an area of multiple cells, you may need to iterate through your cells to test whether any is merged, and if so, perform the intersection test individually for each merged area] :     If testRange.MergeCells Then Set testRange = testRange.MergeArea

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon - There should be no need to check if it's merged. If it isn't `MergeArea` just returns the single cell. So using `MergeArea` for every check should work fine.

Comment: Ah good point - can you see an easier way to do the merged cell check [when the initial inside-range is multiple cells] than iterating through each cell and perhaps adding that cell's MergeArea to a constantly increasing Intersect value, and then comparing the final Intersect with the larger Intersected range?

Comment: OH! I hadn't even tested it in my excitement. Thanks for the heads up + edit guys.